# Stuck on the 'Android is updating' screen after flashing CM13 on LG G3

Tags: cyanogenmod, lg-g3

I did a wipe, and fresh install of CM 13. I did not install gapps. The phone boots fine but gets stuck on the updating white prompt. Restarting the phone by removing the battery gets it stuck on the boot animation. I believe I have the right modem flashed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it not show the progress of the number of apps which have been updated?

Comment: @DhruvilMehta - It does go through all of the apps, but then it gets stuck on the following screen "Android is updating...". It does not matter if I install CM13 by itself, or with the Gapps. I have tried both the regular TWRP and jon777's version.

Comment: Try installing another ROM. How long was the 'Android is updating' screen present? I'm assuming it was present for quite some time. Also make sure that the kernel you're using is compatible with CM13 and the recovery you use.

Comment: What rom do you recommend? AFAIK CM comes with its own kernel.

Comment: I don't own a g3 so I don't know which ROM is considered to be good. I flashed my nexus 5 along time ago and if I remember correctly, CM didn't overwrite the kernel. I was running ElementalX.

Comment: Hmmm. I'll give the kernel route a try.

Comment: I've tried additional 6.0.1 roms, different kernels, and the phone just refuses to boot into CM 13. I think my phone is borked. If anyone else has additional suggestions, I'm willing to try it out.